# Object extends App or Object + def main(...)?

Tags: scala

I think it's a dummy question ...

Is there any difference or advantage between these?

```scala
object SomeApp extends App {
   println("Hello world!")
}
```

```scala
object SomeApp {
   def main(args: List[String]): Unit = {
      println("Hello world!")
   }
}
```

Comment: The first one is roughly equivalent to the second one with some caveats. In general, while I appreciate the effort from the **Scala** maintainers to create something like `App` to ease the getting started experience, reality has shown that it is more trouble than worth it. Just do the second one always; in any case, `App` will despair in **Scala 3**.

Comment: Thank you Luis for clarifying!